# passing user's information into enddrawer flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-layout

So I'm trying to pass all my users info into my drawer. I initiate the method as such

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getDocId(); // initiate futere to get users info
  }
```

after which i call the future

```
 Future getDocId() async {            
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').get().then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach(
            (document) {
              print(document.reference);
              docIDs.add(document.reference.id);
            },
          ),
        );
  }
```

at this point "List docIDs = [];" should have all my current user info. To display the current user's info i would pass docIDs[index] into my enddrawer as such. example

```
endDrawer: my_Drawer(documentId: "docIDs[index]")
```

how would i apply a ListView.builder or any type of builder to pass my users info into my enddrawer. As it stands this doesn't work . My Drawer class takes "final String documentId;"
any clues or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!!

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:myfuji/fetchInfo/userCart.dart';
import 'package:myfuji/screens/Chat.dart';
import 'package:myfuji/screens/News.dart';
import 'package:myfuji/screens/mindYoBis.dart';
import 'package:myfuji/screens/Shop.dart';
import 'package:myfuji/screens/promo.dart';
import '../fetchInfo/my_Drawer.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'SignIn.dart';

class Lobby extends StatefulWidget {
  const Lobby({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Lobby> createState() => _LobbyState();
}

class _LobbyState extends State<Lobby> {

 
  final userUid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    getDocId(); // initiate method to get users info
  }


  List<String> docIDs = []; // list of users

// this future collects all users data
  Future getDocId() async {            
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').get().then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach(
            (document) {
              print(document.reference);
              docIDs.add(document.reference.id);
            },
          ),
        );
  }
// end of future 

  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  int index = 0;
  final screen = [const News(), const mindYoBis(), const Shop(), const Chat()];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
endDrawer: my_Drawer(documentId: "docIDs[index]"), //<- pass user data 
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart,
              ),
              onPressed: () => {
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const userCart()))
              },
            ),
            Builder(builder: (context) {
              return IconButton(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.menu,
                ),
                onPressed: () => {Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer()},
              );
            }),
          ],
          title: const Text('Welcome'),
          leading: Image.asset('src/logo.png'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        ),

        //body
        body: screen[index],
        //body
        bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBarTheme(
          data: NavigationBarThemeData(
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              indicatorColor: Colors.deepPurple[100],
              labelTextStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                  const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))),
          child: NavigationBar(
            labelBehavior: NavigationDestinationLabelBehavior.onlyShowSelected,
            selectedIndex: index,
            onDestinationSelected: (index) =>
                setState(() => this.index = index),
            destinations: const [
              NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home'),
              NavigationDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.emoji_food_beverage_rounded),
                  label: 'Local Bis'),
              NavigationDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag), label: 'Shop'),
              NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.chair), label: 'Games')
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  signOut() async {
    await auth.signOut();
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SignIn()));
  }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what you're exoecting to show in the endDrawer

Comment: i hope using pastebin is ok [link](https://pastebin.com/ZbgNgnsW)

Comment: can you include also a screenshot of what your firestore DB looks like?

Comment: here's a photo of the db [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gYAFcVURqbpmSQVeLtzByoIRi0qs9ZcP/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1):

after see your drawer code with `FutureBuilder`, and you only need the `id` to call `.get()` function.

```
...
future: users.doc(widget.documentId).get(),
...
```

so i think you can add this code below:

```
endDrawer: my_Drawer(documentId: "${docIDs[index]}"), //use curl bracket
```

Comment: I need something like a list builder because i need this to go throw every user detail like this ```builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: docIDs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                home:
                Scaffold(
                  endDrawer: my_Drawer(documentId: docIDs[index]), ```

Comment: please print and show what is  `docIDs` data you get.